# What is the purpose of underscores in front of parameters?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, greeter, conventions

I see contracts that use underscores in front of parameter names, like so:

```
function Greeter(string _greeting) public
{
   greeting = _greeting;
}
```

What's the purpose of these underscores? Do they have a similar meaning as 'internal use' names in Python?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no semantic difference. It is a style used to differentiate between function arguments and global variables.

In this case, it differentiates between the global variable named `greeting` and the corresponding function parameter.

Answer (score 16):

In most situations the storage variable is going to be used in many more places throughout the contract's code.  The function argument may show up in a few places, but in most cases it won't be as prevalent as the storage variable.

It is this developer's opinion that it is nicer to work with `greeter` than `_greeter`. In my code the function argument gets the underscore prefix since I work with it in fewer locations.  This leaves the rest of my code free to use a *normal* variable rather than one that is prefixed.

A less opinionated reason would be that for *public* variables, using an underscore prefixed name would also mean that the *getter* function would have the same name.  This results in a contract ABI in which some of the functions have underscore prefixes which may be confusing to users.

Answer (score 3):

There is a recommendation from [Oyente](https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#conformance-to-solidity-naming-conventions) that

> Allow _ at the beginning of the mixed_case match for private variables
>   and unused parameters.

And says:

> mixedCase (differs from CapitalizedWords by initial lowercase
>   character!)